# API Outlook readWrite

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api, outlook

I have a problem with the outlook API. I want to be able to send mail from my application. I'm on doc

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendMessages

but I don't quite understand. My script is in php/javascript, I don't understand in which language the examples are displayed.
I guess it's a noob question, but I'm going in circles.
If someone has a tuto/advice to understand the doc or someone who has a script that I can learn from.
Thank you, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You are making an HTTP request, they want a body of JSON data. Both languages are capable of doing this.

Typically though, you make a call to your own PHP script because of javascript cross origin policies.

So create an array of the variables, and then `json_encode($yourArray)`, and then make your call.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I'll try, I'll let you know.

Comment: How did you get on?